# How to start a browser service with implicit intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I know that we can open a browser activity with implicit intent:

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But now I want to open a browser **service** to load webpages in background when we click links, so I just do like this:

```
<service ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

But it is **not work**, the app chooser do not appear and the browser service not running.

From the [Intent | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) it saids "android.intent.action.VIEW" is a **Activity Action**, that's mains I can't use it with Service?

Or is there any idea to start a browser service with implicit intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of thinking I found a "hack way" to implement this solution.

Just set activity's theme to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"`, when an implicit intent arrive the activity start, we just do somethings in it's `onCreate()` such as `startService()` and then just `finish()` this activity.

The whole process run very fast and has good experience, looks awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an activity action must be an activity.  Also, you should not use intent filters with services.  Its possible but its highly, highly discouraged.  From the docs

> "Caution: To ensure your app is secure, always use an explicit intent
>   when starting a Service and do not declare intent filters for your
>   services. Using an implicit intent to start a service is a security
>   hazard because you cannot be certain what service will respond to the
>   intent, and the user cannot see which service starts. Beginning with
>   Android 5.0 (API level 21), the system throws an exception if you call
>   bindService() with an implicit intent."

Answer (score 0):

Intent imintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http:\www.google.com"));

try

{

startActivity(imintent);

}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException a)

{
}

You  can use this code for start browser activity implicitly .
not any changes required in Androidmanifeast file.